# ListView.post only work once, but only on some devices

Tags: android, listview

I created a `ListView` whose set can be dynamically added/removed and its height dynamically adjusted using a custom `ArrayAdapter` and a `Runnable` respectively:

Here is how my custom `ArrayAdapter` called `ItemListAdapter` initialized:

```
  private Activity activity;
  public ListView listView;

  public ItemListAdapter(Activity activity, ListView listView...) { //other items are irrelevant
    super(context, resource, values); //typical initalization
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listView = listView;
    ... other codes are irrelevant
  }
```

The important part is that the adapter takes an activity and a `ListView` which is used in that activity's layout.

And then, naturally, I also have the following overridden `notifyDataSetChanged` code which is called when a data set is changed in the adapter:

```
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    if(listView != null) {
      listView.post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //works well but only once
//      activity.runOnUiThread(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //this also not working
    }
  }
```

Since the new height cannot be known before the UI is drawn when the data set is changed, the above `notifyDataSetChanged` is dynamically set up the correct height of the `listView` using `ListView.post` method.

The `Runnable` argument is taken from a `static` method `GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight` in the `ListViewHelper` `class` as shown in the following:

```
  public static Runnable GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(final ListView listView){
    return new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = DataHolder.LvBaseOffset + getHeight(listView, listView.getAdapter()); //this is the actual set up of the view, the view should be changed because of this, except for the first time...
        listView.setLayoutParams(params); //if this is not there, the first show in the main activity will nor be complete (only show the first item)
//        listView.requestLayout(); //not needed
      }
    };
  }
```

And, may not be directly related with the issue, but just for completeness' sake, the `getHeight` method called in the above method is the following:

```
  public static int getHeight(ListView listView, ListAdapter adapter){
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
      View mView = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
      mView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
          View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
      totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    return totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
  }
```

In the layout of the activity, I have an `Add` and `Delete` button which triggers the `notifyDataSetChanged` to be called to add/remove an item and redraw the `ListView` with correct height:

[image]

For example, if the `Add` button is pressed, the result will be the following:

[image]

The above codes work well, at least in my Android simulator, a Hua Wei tablet, and a Xiao Mi phone. And when I say well, it means the `Add` button can be clicked multiple times and it will always produce new row and adjusted the height.

[image]

But when I try to deploy in another device, **it only work once**. What I mean is if I press the `Add` or `Delete` button **the first time**, the item got added/deleted in the `ListView`. But when I click for the second time, the application crash with typical error message box:

```
Unfortunately, [Application Name] has stopped.

                                                   OK
```

Now, I read some posts regarding this which mentions that the problem is likely caused by not running the `Runnable` in the UI thread. Thus, I have the activity added in the construction of the `ItemListAdapter` as shown above and I also try to change the method:

```
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    if(listView != null) {
      listView.post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //works well but only once
//      activity.runOnUiThread(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //this also not working
    }
  }
```

into

```
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    if(listView != null) {
      //listView.post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //works well but only once
      activity.runOnUiThread(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //this also not working
    }
  }
```

But the problem still persists. I also try to give delay:

```
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    if(listView != null) {
      //listView.post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //works well but only once
      activity.runOnUiThread(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //this also not working

      try {
        sleep(500); // does not help
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

And to use `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post`:

```
  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    if(listView != null) {
      //listView.post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //works well but only once
      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(ListViewHelper.GetRunnableSetCorrectHeight(listView)); //this also not working

      try {
        sleep(500); // does not help
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

But *nothing* works and I run out of ideas...

Why is this so? Why does the `post` only work once although I have tried to run on UI thread, using main looper, or give delay? How to fix it?

Comment: try to go for Recyclerview

Comment: @LalitJadav What is it ? How to check/do something by it?

Comment: have you tried listview height to wrap_content?

Comment: Yes, the default height is wrap_content